# Form preview in Django

Tags: python, html, django, forms, django-forms

I am building a registration form. Whenever a user fills the form and clicks the register button I want them to see the preview of their submissions. I am having problems with the arguments. Here goes my code:

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

# Create your models here.
class Register(models.Model):
    regChoice = (
        ('Self', 'Self'),
        ('Group', 'Group'),
        ('Corporate', 'Corporate'),
        ('Others', 'Others'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254,null=True)
    phoneNumber = PhoneNumberField(null=True)
    idCard = models.ImageField(null=True)
    regType = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=regChoice,null=True)
    ticketNo = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

## forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import *

class RegisterForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Your full name...'}))
    email = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Your email...'}))
    phoneNumber = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Your phone number...'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Register
        fields = '__all__'
```

## urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home'),
    path('preview.html/<str:pk>', views.preview, name="preview")
]
```

## views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import *
from .forms import *
# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    form = RegisterForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'event/index.html', context)

def preview(request, pk):
    reg = Register.objects.get(id=pk)
    prev = RegisterForm(instance=reg)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST, instance=reg)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    context = {'reg':reg, 'prev':prev}
    return render(request, 'event/preview.html', context)
```

## index.html

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Event Registration</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
    <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="mobile-screen">
        <div class="header">
        </div>
        
        <div class="logo"></div>
      
        <form id="login-form" method="POST" action="{% url 'preview' form.id %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
                {{form.name}}
                {{form.email}}
                {{form.phoneNumber}}
                <legend style="color: aliceblue;">Upload ID card: </legend>{{form.idCard}}
                <div style="text-align: center; color: aliceblue;">Registration Type: {{form.regType}}</div>
                {{form.ticketNo}}
                <input class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit" value="Register" name="Register">
        </form>
        
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

## preview.html

```
Hello {{prev.name}},
your email is {{prev.email}}
your phone number is {{prev.phoneNumber}}
your idCard photo is {{prev.idCard.url}}
your registration type is {{prev.regType}}
your number of tickets is {{prev.ticketNo}}
```

The error I am having is:

> ***NoReverseMatch at /***
>
> Reverse for 'preview' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['preview\.html/(?P[^/]+)$']

Comment: Maybe theis `path('preview.html/<str:pk>'` should be `path('preview/<str:pk>'`

Comment: @johnashu dude that worked. Thanks. But the image is not loading in my preview page. What shall I change ```{{prev.idCard.url}}``` to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When someone reaches your index page and enters the form we need to

1. Submit the form as a POST request to index view
2. Save the form thereby creating a model in the DB
3. Redirect the user to preview view using the above id

To do that the code needs to be somewhat like this, I have not tested it, but you should get the idea.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def index(request):
    form = RegisterForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegisterForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save()
            return redirect('preview', pk=instance.id)
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'event/index.html', context)
```

Inside your index.html change

```
action="{% url 'preview' form.id %}"
```

to

```
action=""
```

as we want it to post to the INDEX view as that is where out POST handling logic is.

The index view then redirects to preview using the newly generated object.

Also as mentioned by @Snir in the other answer, having `.html` in URLS is not a standard practice. It would be better to simple make it something like:

```
path('preview/<str:pk>', views.preview, name="preview")
```

Comment: That worked like magic. Now the only problem I am having is the image is not loading in the preview page.
What shall I change ```your idCard photo is {{prev.idCard.url}}``` to?

Comment: @DeepjyotiDe Use `<img src="{{reg.idCard.url}}">` or `<img src="{{ prev.idCard.url }}">` Glad I could be of help, please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted if all is working fine :)

Comment: The photo isn't loading yet. The default image icon is showing with the alternate text.

Comment: # settings.py
```STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')```

Comment: Can you check if the file exists in that directory on the filesystem?

Comment: Also have you enabled Media files to be served by runserver in debug mode using these instructions: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development ?

Comment: the image does exist in media folder.

Comment: Well, the image is loading in the admin site, but not in my preview page.

Comment: ```{% load static %}
Hello {{prev.name}},

your idCard photo is <img src="{{prev.idCard.url}}" alt="idCard">

```

Comment: Can you try adding proper symantic html and body tags around? It could be that its being rendered as plain text instead of html.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214574/discussion-between-deepjyoti-de-and-oxalorg).

Answer (score 1):

The URL patterns are regexes, so you'll have to escape special regex characters, like the dot. Try (add r) or remove the dot:

```
    path(r'preview.html/<str:pk>', views.preview, 
    name="preview")
```

Comment: The image is not loading in my preview page.
what shall I change ```{{prev.idCard.url}}``` to?

Comment: use:
<img src="{{prev.idCard.url}}" alt="">

Comment: now the image isn't loading but that image icon is showing.

Comment: ```STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

#settings.py

Comment: ***Not Found: /media/portfolio-5.jpg***
  in my command prompt